# Computing drone camera footprint over a DTM

Tags: python, dem, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, footprint

I am developing a Python application to compute the footprint of aerial videos. I am able to compute the footprint when the sensor is parallel to the terrain and the terrain surface is plane.

Now, I am looking for a way to compute the footprint of the drone camera over a DTM which is a raster. Is there a "Python" way of doing this without having to create a 3D mesh from the DTM?

Comment: Please include your current code attempt and describe where exactly you get stuck, otherwise your question is likely to be closed.  From the guidelines: *When seeking help to debug/write/improve code always provide the desired behavior, a specific problem/error and the shortest code (as formatted text, not pictures) needed to reproduce it in the question body. Providing a clear problem statement and a code attempt helps others to help you.*

Comment: ArcGIS has a tool to calculate a line surface intersection that could be incorporated into a script if you have the license.  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/3d-analyst/intersect-3d-line-with-surface.htm